# How to supply a context paramter to RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my RecyclerView.ViewHolder, I want to check if there is network and unhide a progress bar if it returns true.

I use this class to check for Network connectivity:

```
public class NetworkCheck {

    public static boolean isAvailableAndConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean isNetworkAvailable = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
        boolean isNetWorkConnected = isNetworkAvailable && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

        return isNetWorkConnected;

    }

}
```

Then in RecyclerView.ViewHolder I am doing this:

```
public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button loadButton;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
            super(footerView);
            loadButton = (Button) footerView.findViewById(R.id.reload_button);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) footerView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);

            if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(Context)) {
                loadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    }
```

In line `if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(Context)) {` Android Studio red-underlined **Context** with the message: "Expression expected". I have tried `context`, `getApplicationContext`, `getBaseContext`, `this` but none of them seems to be working.

Please,  where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Your view holder is static, So put it in the Adapter you're extending, Then pass the context you used to inflate this holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrive the context using the footerView object:

```
 public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
                //...
                 public ProgressViewHolder(View footerView){
                    if(NetworkCheck.isAvailableAndConnected(footerView.getContext())) {
                       // Do stuff

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

`getContext` is only available to activities, fragments, or views.

In your case you should just use your `itemView` passed to your view holder.

Use either `footerView.getContext` or `itemView.getContext` to call the method of the `View` instance.

Comment: Just add parentheses to one of the 2 examples in the last paragraph to call the function and get the context...

Answer (score 0):

As you know you need a `Context` object to `inflate` your `itemView` and create holders in `onCreateViewHolder` method, So keep an instance in your adapter, This way you have a reference to `Context` object every time you need it, Something like this:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ProgressViewHolder> {
       Context mContext //you need this to inflate views
       public Adapter(Context context, arguments you need...) {
              mContext = context; //here you keep an reference to Context object
              ...
       }
    ... 
    static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //your implementation
    }
}
```